# Windows 7 Git Bash and OpenShift git clone

Tags: git, bash, ssh, openshift

i've read a lot if solutions here and there but git clone won't work from my Git Bash in Windows7.

What i've done:

- use puttygen to create a Key.
- saved public and private key in  the C:/Users/MyUser/.ssh <---.ssh wasn't there, i've added manually
- Copied Key from Textarea of keygen and pasted to Openshift Settings project
- started Git Bash in my Windows 7 and tried the git clone but:

> MyUser@0000000 /H/test/prompt $ git clone ssh://--- copied from
>   Openshift Git path--- Cloning into 'MyProject'... Permission denied
>   (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic). fatal: Could not read from
>   remote repository.

and

> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

So i've tried:

- eval $(ssh-agent)
- ssh-add 'C:\Users\MyUser.ssh'

but nothing has changed.
So i'm stuck...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to create the key using command-line `ssh-keygen` supplied with Git Bash? Just open Git Bash command prompt and invoke `ssh-keygen` or `ssh-keygen -t dsa` there.

Comment: The previous commenter is correct: You're trying to use PuTTY, which lives in the Windows world, with Git Bash, which includes its own version of OpenSSH. These two things don't easily work together.

Answer (score 0):

What is about trying next?

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add
```